# Drupal: Importing users from CSV - how to specify username, password, email and role

Tags: drupal, csv, import, drupal-modules

I'm looking for the best method to import user data from excel/CSV files directly into the users database in Drupal 7.

The procedure needs to import the following items from the CSV:
- username
- password
- email address
- role

I've tried out the User import framework - which just lets you do email, username and password. If anybody can suggest some info on how to extend this to work for roles that would be awesome.
http://drupal.org/project/uif

Also, I've tried, feeds, which I've managed to get to import the username, and email address into a specific role (not specifying role in the CSV) but it doesn't seem to allow the option to import the password.
http://drupal.org/project/feeds

Can anybody suggest a way I can work with either of these modules, or maybe a different way?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After over a year working on building these kinds of solutions, I now would like to say that the best solution is still to use the http://drupal.org/project/feeds module which does indeed allow you to import passwords. This solution works well for one off, or user managed imports. It may also work well for periodic imports where you upload an updated CSV file to a location on the server.

Another alternative may be to use the Migrate module.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)? I'm not completely sure this will work, but I've done simliar things with nodes in D6:

1. Add a textfield to users (admin/config/people/accounts/fields), name it "Role".
2. In uif, is there a way to map your "role" column to a field? Then do it here!
3. Use VBO to select those with a specific "Role" field value, then add the real user role you want.

I'm not 100% sure that step 2 works, but I would definitely give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

User Import Framework http://drupal.org/project/uif let you import the role: "Out of the box, this module supports import of {user} table fields such as mail, name, pass, roles, created, timezone, and language."

And it provide some hook if you need some more advance logic.